# Push image or <h2> down a bit

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I placed a logo (a Microsoft logo) on my panel's header with `<center><h2> img scr...</h2></center>`

It's at the center where I want it; However, it's a bit high on the top of my panel's header, so it's not exactly at the center vertically wise.

This the CSS of the whole panel (it's header included):

```
.panel {
    background: url("../images/panel_bg2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width:148px;
    height:270px;

}


.panel_header {
    background: url("../images/panel_header_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width:149px;
    height:54px;
    position:absolute;


}
```

This is the html :

```
<div class="panel">
<div class="panel_header">
<center><h2><img src="images/ms_logo.png" width="102" height="21" /> </h2></center>
```

Is there any way I can move the image ( the Microsoft logo) down a bit ?

You can see what I'm talking about here: http://www.qubespace.com/certwizard/
The panel is right under the slide. I just want to push the logo (the Microsoft logo) a bit down in the header div.
I know I'm missing something.

I will greatly appreciate a response.

Thank You !

PS: The framework I'm using is Wordpress, and the html is placed in a widget. I'm using U-Design theme.

Comment: The CertWizard logo is what you want to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a margin-top rule to your panel class to move the Microsoft logo up or down. Negative values move it up, positive values down. If you want to center it, set the margin to `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: are you referring to .panel {   or .panel_header {

Comment: Setting the margin on .panel should do it. Worked here when I tested with dev console.

Comment: Seems like it pushed the whole panel down, not just the logo.

Comment: I think I didn't understand exactly which element you wanted to move. Try adding the margin to the `.panel_header img` element.

Comment: Yeah that too didn't work. The logo is not supported by the CSS, so margin calls were not going to work anyway. But I may have solved the problem. 
"#before-content-column h2, #before-content-column h3 { " had a margin-top of 5px;, blocking any <h2> element from moving down. This is not a theme designed by me, so I knew little that that was the problem until I looked around a little more, thanks to you. Haha. Thank you very much for helping me out j08691.